# swift 4: return false, validating webservice login data

Tags: swift, web-services, validation, segue

I need validate the login auth before show the next view. I know how "print" these error, but I need return false to prevent the segue.

I use the prepare function to get the JSON data from the webservice:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        do {
            let username   = txtUsername.text
            let password   = txtPassword.text

            // webservice
            let urlString = "http://myweb.com/api/user/username/\(username!)/password/\(password!)/key/xxx"

            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                let datosWeb = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                // json
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: datosWeb, options: [])
                if let temp = jsonObject as? [[String:String]] {
                    self.items = temp
                }
            } else {
                print("URL not exists") // I need a return false
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error obtaining data") // I need a return false
        }
    }
```

So the prepare function doesn't have a bool output. I have a text field validation with the shouldPerformSegue, but I need a similar function to validate "after".

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if (txtUsername.text?.isEmpty)! || (txtPassword.text?.isEmpty)! {
            showAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please, complete the fields.")
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a login button to trigger the login, so you should do this in your login button logic:

```
func loginClicked() {
    if (txtUsername.text?.isEmpty)! || (txtPassword.text?.isEmpty)! {
        showAlert(title: "Error", message: "Please, complete the fields.")
    }
    else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueID", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

No need to pass a bool variable. If your validation passes do your segue.

Comment: Thanks, it was much easier than I thought